# JAVA PDF Compare On PDF Documents From Different States

Tags: java, selenium, pdf, automation, cucumber

I am an automation engineer (working in a Java framework) and recently due to compliance issues I have a need to create a test that compares multiple pdf documents. The pdf documents are of a legal nature and contain different verbiage per state. I have never done this before. Just looking for implementation suggestions, was hoping to avoid something yucky. I would be accessing each document via a link, which would open in Docusign. The scenario would be open the document for New York and then compare it to a baseline document for New York, open a document for Maryland and then compare it to a baseline document for Maryland, open a document for Virginia and compare it to a baseline document for Virginia, etc.

Comment: You can refer this link https://github.com/red6/pdfcompare

Comment: Are you looking for a purely visual comparison? Or do you also need to compare internals of the document? If the latter, which internals?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I think a visual comparison is what I'm looking for, I was hoping that by doing that I would also be comparing the content of the document. Just a quick note, the docusign pdf opens in the browser so I would need a solution that can compare the document in the browser.

Comment: You need to download that PDF .. n then compare them. With base